# Ball can double jump in Jumper Game

Tags: java, user-interface, game-physics

I wrote a game that has a ball which can only jump (like in most jumper games) to avoid incoming obstacles (only, I haven't integrated the obstacles part yet). Right now, it's just a ball that can jump. The problem is, is that when the ball is on its way back down, it can jump, resulting in a double jump. I only want my ball to have one jump at a time. How can I fix this?

Main

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        View view = new View();
        Jumper jumper = new Jumper();
        Model model = new Model(view, jumper);
        view.setJumper(jumper);

        frame.setSize(500, 460);
        frame.getContentPane().add(view);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

View

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class View extends JPanel {
    private Jumper jumper;
    private Rectangle bounds;
    private Model model;

    public View() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 400);

        addKeyBinding("space.pressed", KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, new MoveAction(true, Key.SPACE), false);
        addKeyBinding("space.released", KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, new MoveAction(false, Key.SPACE), true);
    }

    public void addKeyBinding(String name, int keyEvent, AbstractAction action, boolean pressed) {
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyEvent, 0, pressed), name);
        actionMap.put(name, action);
    }

    public void setJumper(Jumper jumper) {
        this.jumper = jumper;
    }

    public Rectangle getViewBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        jumper.paint(g);
    }

    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

Jumper

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Jumper {
    private Point location;
    private Dimension dimension;
    private Graphics graphics;

    public Jumper() {
        location = new Point(250, 250);
        dimension = new Dimension(20, 20);
    }

    public Dimension getSize() {
        return dimension;
    }

    public void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void callPaint() {
        paint(graphics);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        graphics = g;
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(location.x, location.y, dimension.width, dimension.height);
    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

Model

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Model {

    private boolean canBePressed, jumping;
    private int ballX, ballY;
    private int jumpCounter;
    private Thread thread;
    private Jumper jumper;
    private View view;
    private Timer timer1;
    private Point point;
    static Set<Key> key;

    public Model(View view, Jumper jumper) {
        this.view = view;
        view.setModel(this);
        canBePressed = false;
        jumping = false;
        key = new HashSet<Key>(3);
        this.jumper = jumper;
        ballX = 250;
        ballY = 0;
        thread = new Thread();

        timer1 = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                update();
                view.repaint();
            }

        });
        timer1.start();
    }

    public void update() {

        if (jumping) {
            // Only enter when space is pressed
            if (jumpCounter <= 100) {
                ballY--;
                jumpCounter++;
            } else {
                jumping = false;
            }
        } else {

            if (canBePressed && !key.isEmpty()) {
                // Start jumping (set variable to true)
                jumpCounter = 0;
                jumping = true;
                canBePressed = false;
            }

            if (jumper.getLocation().y + jumper.getSize().height > view.getViewBounds().height) {
                // Make the ball unable to jump
                canBePressed = true;
            } else {
                ballY++;
            }

        }

        //Set location of ball
        point = new Point(ballX, ballY);
        jumper.setLocation(point);
        point = null;
    }

}
```

Key

```
public enum Key {
    SPACE
}
```

MoveAction

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;

public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

    private boolean pressed;
    private Key direction;

    public MoveAction(boolean pressed, Key direction) {
        this.pressed = pressed;
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (pressed) {
            if (Model.key.size() < 1)
                Model.key.add(direction);
        } else {
            Model.key.remove(direction);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: try asking this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you mean it can jump in mid air? or _immediately_ after touchdown?

Comment: When the ball is on its way up, it can't jump, but as it's on its way down, it can jump again for some reason. On touchdown of course, it can jump again, though.